# Vertical alignment of multi column figures

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I got this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{15 cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
   \includegraphics[width=.65\columnwidth]{./images/Cap3/acel_3d.PNG} 
   \includegraphics[scale=0.44]{./images/Cap4/TTN_ejemplo_caidaFrontal.png} 
\end{multicols}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.51]{./images/Cap4/putty.png}\par 

\end{minipage}}
\caption{caption..}
\label{f:3-2}
\end{figure}
```

and LATEX show this:

[image]

But, I really want to vertical align the first picture in order to looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but compilable document), which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will ask with a compilable document next time. Thanks for your time again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try all images encapsulated in `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{15 cm}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.44\linewidth}
       \includegraphics{./images/Cap3/acel_3d.PNG}
    \end{minipage}%
        \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.54\linewidth}
       \includegraphics[height=3cm]{./images/Cap4/TTN_ejemplo_caidaFrontal.png} % in real document remove "[height=3cm]"
    \end{minipage}

\smallskip
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{./images/Cap4/putty.png}\par
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}%
    }
\caption{caption ...}
\label{f:3-2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]